# how make a script refresh and redirecting for Ajax.BeginForm MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I created a form using `Ajax.BeginForm`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePlayer", "Admin", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="text-style-roboto form-group">
            <label>Имя</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="button button-create">Добавить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I push the button to make a new player, a player is created but the form stays filled.

[image],

The desired behaviour is that the form should be cleared, but it doesn't. I don't how to clear the form using jQuery. Should I refresh the page, or some other way.

My post action in controller is -

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreatePlayer(CreatePlayerModel model, string TeamNameId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (TeamNameId != string.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    int newTeamId = int.Parse(TeamNameId);
                    repository.CreatePlayer(model, newTeamId);
                    TempData["message"] = string.Format("Игрок {0} {1} сохранены", model.Name, model.Surname);

                    return new JsonResult()
                    {
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                        Data = new { result = "success" }
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = new SelectList(repository.Teams, "Id ", "Name");
        ViewBag.ChoosingTeam = list;
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { result = "error" }
        };
    }
```

If it's needed, I can do the action by html forms to Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AJAX, the form would not be cleared automatically and you need to clear it. You can set values of input text and textareas to `''`. Also, you need to reset the values of selects.

Assuming that the form id is `CreatePlayer` then to set the values of input text and textarea to blank (`''`) -

```
$('#CreatePlayer').find("input[type=text], textarea").val('');
```

Similarly, you can set the value of select to default value of your choice. Assuming that the select to be reset by the first option and the id of select is `teamSel`, then to reset the value -

```
$("#teamSel").val($("#teamSel option:first").val());
```

If you have a reset button added in the form, you can trigger the reset but that won't set the default values to form inputs. To trigger the reset -

```
$("#CreatePlayer").trigger('reset');
```

__ UPDATE ___

You should be calling these(depending on your requirement), in `OnSuccess` and/or `OnFailure`.

You should clear the form when AJAX call returns with success. That said, inside `OnSuccess`, clear the form.

You should show errors if `OnFailure` is called.

Comment: it's need making in a function which calling by onSuccess in aajaxOptions or on submit in html attributes?

Comment: @Andrei Glad I could help. Would appreciate if you could accept as answer :)